# CakePHP "cake schema generate" command is not creating table relationships

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I just used the "cake schema generate" command to generate a schema.php file in order to migrate the database schema of my cakePHP application.

When I use the command "cake schema create" in the new database, it creates the tables but all the relations between them are not present.

Why is this happening? do I have to use any parameter to include this relations?

Comment: Only the innoDB database engine supports relations. Did you check new tables are created as 'innoDB' ?

Comment: Yes, all the tables are created using innoDB

Comment: It would help to see at least a Model definition.